# Is $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$ a field? My guess is no because I think $$\Bbb Q[\sqrt{2}]\cong \Bbb Q[x]/(x^2-2)$$ and that polynomial is reducible. But I feel I am overcomplicating things and I'm not sure if I am correct.

What's a simpler way of seeing that this thing is not a field? (Or is it a field?)

Comment: How do you reduce this polynomial ?

Comment: It is a field and $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$

Comment: What about $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$? This is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2-2)$ but the polynomial ring $\Bbb Z[x]$ is no longer a PID. Do we still get a field here?

Comment: It's a field. That polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: @CactusShmactus no. $(x^2 -2)$ is a prime ideal yet not maximal in Z[x].

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an explicit element which does not have an inverse, @quid?

Comment: $Z[\sqrt{2}]$ is not a field as multiplicative inverse of $\sqrt{2}$ is not present in it.

Comment: Sure, any integer other than $\pm 1$.

Comment: Haha, of course. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways to see that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ is a field:

- $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, so $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID. The element $x^2-2$ is irreducible (as it is a quadratic and has no root in $\mathbb{Q}$), so it is prime (irreducible $\Rightarrow$ prime in PID). So $(x^2-2)$ is a prime ideal. But again because we are in a PID, this ideal $(x^2-2)$ is actually maximal. And it is a standard fact that the quotient of a ring by maximal ideal is a field.
- One can also write $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]=\{a+b\sqrt{2}: a, b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ and show explicitly that it is a field. So show that it is closed under addition, and multiplication. In other words, show that the product of $a+b\sqrt{2}$ and $c+d\sqrt{2}$ (where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$) can again be written in the form $s+t\sqrt{2}$ with $s,t\in\mathbb{Q}$. Finally, let's show that it is closed under inverses: if $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is non-zero, then first check that $a^2-2b^2\neq 0$ (you will need the fact that $\sqrt{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}$) and then check that
  $$
  \frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}} = \frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a^2-2b^2} = \frac{a}{a^2-2b^2} + \left(\frac{-b}{a^2-2b^2}\right)\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]
  $$

Comment: Yeah, in this particular case, this is really standard high-school-level computational material. The problem for all of us (or most) is that we don’t apply those exercises we did back then to these much more abstract and (in my opinion) much more interesting situations.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, because it has no roots (and has degree $2$).

In general, if $L$ is an extension field of $F$ and $b\in L$ is algebraic over the field $F$, then $F[b]=F(b)$. Here $F[b]$ is the image of the ring homomorphism $F[x]\to L$ fixing $F$ and sending $x$ to $b$; $F(b)$ is the minimal subfield of $L$ containing $F$ and $b$.

Since $F[b]\subseteq F(b)$ for obvious reasons, it is sufficient to see that $F[b]$ is a field, that is, every nonzero element has an inverse in $F[b]$.

A nonzero element $c\in F[b]$ is again algebraic over $F$, because $F(c)\subseteq F(b)$ and so the extension $F(c)/F$ is finite. If $g(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n$ is the minimal polynomial of $c$ over $F$, we have $a_0\ne0$ (or the polynomial would be reducible) and from
$$
a_0c^{-1}=a_1+a_2c+\dots+a_{n-1}c^{n-2}+c^{n-1}
$$
we get
$$
c^{-1}=\alpha_0+\alpha_1c+\dots+\alpha_{n-1}c^{n-1}\in F[c]\subseteq F[b]
$$

Answer (score 1):

Thr maximal ideals of $\mathbf Z[x]$ have the for $(p, f(x))$, where $p$ is a prime, and $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial modulo $p$.

Comment: $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: It needs to be irreducible modulo $p$ because of this example: $p=2$, $f(x)=x^2+1$.

Comment: That's right. I've added this point. Thanks!